# jhipster hot deploy on client side using npm

Tags: npm, webpack, jhipster

I am using version 4.5.5 of jhipster.
My OS is Linux Mint.
I am using IntelliJ as my IDE.

Everything is working fine in terms of generating the code, building and running the code.

**Client**
Unfortunately, when I make changes to the client code (html or ts), the changes are not reflected until I recompile the client code completed.  To achieve this I do "mvn -Pdev,webpack".  It takes quite a while to restart the client and this is really holding me back.

**Hot Deploy**
What I expect to happen is that I can run "npm start" and when I save a change to a ts or a html file that it will be picked up and the change immediately visible in the browser.

**Questions**

Any ideas why the client hot deploy is not working ?

Any ideas how I identify where the issue is ?

For example, how do I know what folders are being watched by the hot deploy ?

Thanks a million for you help.

I am sure others have encountered the same issue and will read the answer gladly.

Kind regards,
Fergal.

PS Need any details, simply ask.

Comment: Well it seems to work as [documented](https://jhipster.github.io/development/#working-with-angular) for everyone but you. When `npm start`runs, you can see it works by modifying a file and seeing that it triggers recompilation. Of course to see changes your browser must point to http://localhost:9000 (webpack server), if it points to http://localhost:8080 it won't work..

Comment: Thanks.  I expect you're right in that it is an environmental issue rather than an issue with jhipster.  I was hoping for some pointers on how to troubleshoot the issue - that way I can work through it.

I am running version v.8.0.0 of node.
node -v
v8.0.0

I expect there are a few others with the same issue - same environmental issue I expect.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou - perhaps you might be able to give me a few pointers on how to resolve this issue for me (e.g. how does jhipster work with webpack? where is the config that I need to look at ? how do I troubleshoot this issue).  Appreciate your time and help.

Comment: As [documented](https://jhipster.github.io/installation/) JHipster does support only LTS versions of Node, so not 8.x nor 7.x, please try installing current LTS.

Comment: Thanks @GaëlMarziou. I will do that.  Do you think that this is causing my issue ?  I'll be able to do that this evening and I'll post up the result.

Comment: Maybe. if it still does not work, you could try [jhipster-devbox](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-devbox) which is a Vagrant configuration that isolates you completely from your own environment. Docker is also another option. Regarding hints for troubleshooting, the only one I can imagine is searching for issues of webpack dev server and look at jhipster webpack configuration in webpack directory in your project

Comment: Figured it out. Somebody else had a similar issue with a globally installed instance of webpack.  I installed a local version and the files are being detected and recompiled and the app hot deployed. Now working perfectly.   To install a local version https://webpack.js.org/guides/installation/#local-installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Somebody else had a similar issue with a globally installed instance of webpack.

I installed a local version and the file updates are being detected and recompiled and the app hot deployed. Now working perfectly.

To install a local version webpack.js.org/guides/installation/#local-installation.